# is it possible to train a new Stanford NER model, and combine it with the existing one?

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

All,

Here is what I am hoping to do -

For now, Stanford NER can recognize PERSON, LOCATION and ORGANIZATION. I would like to add more details to these categories - for example, I would like to make sure some more locations/persons/organizations can be recognized. So I am thinking to train my own model, as described [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#a).

Another good tutorial about training your own NER tagger is given [here](https://dataturks.com/blog/stanford-core-nlp-ner-training-java-example.php?s=so).

Now, my question is, once I use my own training data to create a new model, would it be possible to **combine** this new model with the existing Stanford model? I would like to add *extra* capabilities to the existing model, I don't really want to totally replace it with my own model.

Hope I made my question clear. Many thanks to any input.

Answer (score 3):

Here is more info on training the `ner`:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html

The `ner` annotator will run a series of sequence taggers in a row.

You can set this with the `ner.model` parameter.

For instance you could set it to:

```
my_model.ser.gz,edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz,edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz,edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz
```

This will allow you to get the results of all these models...though there isn't a way to "combine" them into one model.  It will just run each model one after the other.  And a subsequent model can't overwrite tagging decisions by a previous model.

You can also write rules and those will be applied as well.  I probably will spend some time in the near future trying to make it a little clearer how/easier to integrate your own custom models/rules with the baseline we provide.

Comment: got it. thank you!